# Visual Workflow: Not able to view fields accessible via API or via standard page

Tags: visual-workflow, fields

I'm trying to create several sObj through visual workflow. In a couple of the standard junction objects important id fields are not showing up.

Let's take "Quote" for instance. I'm trying to connect it to an Account. The lookup(account) field seems to be there:

---

[image: from schema builder]

---

### [image: from dev console]

but in a visual workflow record create:

---

[image]

### [image]

This also seemed to be the case with the productid for OpportunityQuoteLineItem. Field is in the schema, in the API, in the standard salesforce page layout. I was able to add it, edit it, delete it, totally accessible field. But it just isn't in visual workflow. I've checked all of the permissions on the field (showing opportunitylineitem.product2):

---

[image]

---

Any clue what is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that field represents the id of the account on the associated opp, and can't be set manually, which is why you don't see it.

If you look at

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_quote.htm

You should see all fields that have the create and update properties.  Accountid does not have that property.

Comment: and hence by setting the Quote.OpportunityId, the Quote.accountId will get automatically updated by SFDC "internals". To @ZAR, `OpportunityLineItem.Product2Id` is "auto-derived' by SFDC once the `OpportunityLineItem.PricebookEntryId` is set.

Comment: So I don't need to explicitly set these fields? I don't like this "magic" happening!